# Restrict Particular Records in Bulk Edit Form based on Drop down value exists in record and thrown error

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

To throw error if particular Field Drop down value is there in records and restrict users when in bulk edit through script.

We use our application in a manufacturing setting, I definitely don't want our floor guys to be able to edit front office options like accounting, inventory-tracking, etc. And vice versa, I don't want our front office people to be able to modify options that are specific to our floor guys. Not only to prevent errors, but to keep the program simple and easy to use. The user sees only what he/she needs to see, not everything at once.

Anyway, because bulk edit can't be limited I had to disable bulk editing for the whole company. And they are frustrated that they can only edit one record at a time. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Bulk edit form is not a separate form so it’s not customizable, and you can never add/execute script to bulk edit form mode in any supported way. But you can try this [unsupported approach](https://celedonpartners.com/blog/how-to-create-a-dynamic-bulk-edit-form-in-dynamics-365/), again this is unsupported & not recommended.

Instead you can have multiple entity forms & security role can be used to show/hide for different teams. That may solve your problem as the form user last visited will be used in bulk edit mode. [Read more](https://www.encloud9.com/blog/using-multiple-forms-in-crm-2011-and-creating-custom-appointments-in-outlook/)